# Remove css class when reached a div (anchor point)

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

I would like to remove a class from a div (my header) when the page scrolled to an element (When that element has reached the top of viewport).

I did this :

```
var sh = $("#scrolledhero").offset().top;
    $(document).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).height() + $(this).scrollTop() > sh) {
            $('header').removeClass('lightHeader');
        }
    });
```

Inside my page, I added a trigger :

```
<a id="#scrolledhero">Trigger</a>
```

I can't make it work. Can you help me? Thank you

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "scrolled to an element"? Do you mean when that element is in the viewport (partially, completely) or when that element has reached the top of the viewport?

Comment: I mean when the trigger element has reached the top of the viewport.

Comment: In the end, I used Intersection Observer instead and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it differently, using Intersection Observer, and it works: it detects when my div element is partially inside the viewport or not. I am not the best in JS, so maybe it can be simplified.

```
var header = document.getElementById("test2");
    
    if ( header.classList.contains('lightHeader')) {
        function handler(entries, observer) {
            for (entry of entries) {
                if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                    if ( header.classList.contains('lightHeader')) {
                        // do nothing
                        } else {
                            header.classList.add("lightHeader");
                        }
                } else {
                    header.classList.remove("lightHeader");
                }
            }
        }
       let observer = new IntersectionObserver(handler);
       observer.observe(document.getElementById("findme"));     

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure about your specific case. But there is a plugin by using which you can trigger a function when an element is in the viewport.

You can use a small plugin of jquery. Its name is `WayPoint`. By using that you can call your function like this. [[Way Point]](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/)

```
$(function() {
       $('#yourdiv').waypoint(function() {
         window.location.href = 'http://facebook.com'; || //do your thing
         }, {
           offset: '100%'
         });
    });
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your answer. I used Intersection Observer instead. More simple for my need.